# Using Iterative Gradient Descent to Determine to determine the Transformation for a Registration Algorithm

Tags: least-squares, nonlinear

Based on the paper ["Iterative Estimation of Rotation and Translation using the Quaternion"](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub1/wheeler_m_d_1995_1/wheeler_m_d_1995_1.pdf) I am trying to define find the transformation, i.e. the rotation and scaling, that registers points from the set $X = \left\{x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_N \right\}$ to the set $P = \left\{p_0, p_1, \dotsc, p_N \right\}$. Lets say I have the pairs of points that should 'touch', i.e. Correspondences = $\left\{(x_0, p_0), (x_1, p_1), \dotsc, (x_N, p_N) \right\}$.

I want to minimise the following error with iterative gradient descent:
$$
E(\vec{q}_c, \vec{t}, X, P) = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i = 0}^{N} f\left(\vec{q}_c, \vec{t}, \vec{x}_i, \vec{p}_i\right)
$$

where $\vec{q}_c \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is the current rotation, $\vec{t} \in \mathbb{R}^4$ the translation, $\vec{x}_i \in X$, $\vec{p}_i \in P$, and
$$
f\left(\vec{q}_c, \vec{t}, \vec{x}, \vec{p}\right) = \left(R(\vec{q}_c)\vec{x} + \vec{t} - \vec{p} \right)^2
$$
is taken from the paper (section 6.1 on page 8). The function $R(\vec{q}_c)$ computes a rotation matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ from the quaternion $\vec{q}_c$. The paper also gives the rotational $\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{q}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I} \right)$ and translational $\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{t}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I} \right)$ gradient of $f(\bullet)$ evaluated at $\vec{q}_I = [0, 0, 0, 1]^T$.

Thus 
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{q}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I} = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i = 0}^{N} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{q}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{t}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I} = \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i = 0}^{N} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{t}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I}
$$

As far as I understand the paper, the partial derivatives defined at $\vec{q}_I$ require the points $\vec{x}_i \in X$ to be premultiplied with $R(\vec{q}_c)$. This transforms these points to a coordinate system where the current quaternion $\left(\vec{q}_c\right)$ equals $\vec{q}_I$.

I think this results in this iterative gradient descent algorithm with the learning rate $\alpha$:

> $\vec{q}_c = \vec{q}_I$;
>   $\vec{t}_c = \vec{0}$;
>
> `while not convergence`
>
> > $X_c$ = `premultiply`$\left(X,\,\vec{q}_c\right)$;
> >
> > $\vec{q}_p = \vec{q}_c$;
> >     $\vec{t}_p = \vec{t}_c$;
> >
> > $\vec{t}_c = \vec{t}_p - \alpha \frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{t}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_i, \vec{t} = \vec{t}_p, X = X_c, P = P}$
> >
> > $\vec{q}_c = \alpha \frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{q}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_i, \vec{t} = \vec{t}_p, X = X_c, P = P} \: \vec{q}_p$

Is this the correct gradient descent algorithm?

I've created a quick and dirty Matlab script for testing, I have published it [here](https://gist.github.com/lauraBaakman/720bdd9b8b6a15e5fea524520e9f1c54) for the interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper actually provides the answer in section 4 around equation number 9, to paraphrase:

> The gradient direction, $\vec{dq}$, with respect to $\vec{q}$ will
>   have no $s$ ($\vec{q} = [u, v, w, s]^T$ component, and will be of the
>   form:
>
> $$ \vec{dq} = - \frac{\partial f}{\partial q}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_I} =
> > [du,\, dv,\, dw,\, 0]^T = [\vec{du},\, 0]^T $$
>
> and each step of each successive rotation in this direction will be of the form:
>
> $$ \vec{q}' = \vec{q}_I + \alpha \cdot \vec{dq} = [\alpha \cdot \vec{du},\, 1]^T$$

The update rule for $\vec{q}$ in the algorithm thus becomes:

> > $\vec{dq} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial \vec{q}}|_{\vec{q} = \vec{q}_i, \vec{t} = \vec{t}_p, X = X_c, P = P} \: \vec{q}_p$
> >
> > $\vec{q}_c = [-\alpha \cdot \vec{du},\, 1]$